# Eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an Interface class checked out from an svn project, and created an `Interface_Tester` class to preview the interface. However, when I try to run it in Eclipse I get the following error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class Interface_Tester**

Here is the code from the interface_tester class -

```
public class Interface_Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Interface test = new Interface();
    }
}
```

I have seen a similar question asked on here but did not understand the answer. I need a step-by-step guide to the solution as I am a beginner. Thank you

UPDATE:
I tried running the Interface class itself and had the same error... All classes are being shown in the project explorer on the left so why is eclipse unable to locate any of them?

Comment: Has it definitely compiled okay? (And calling a class `Interface` is somewhat misleading, IMO...)

Comment: When you click on the Run Configuations button (black caret next to green circle with white triangle in it), do you see `Interface_Tester` in the list? Also, 2nding Jon Skeet ... rename the class.

Comment: There are no errors in either class, if that is what you mean. I have tried cleaning the project also. Not sure if it is an issue with the way the project files are stored.

Comment: please provide the exacpt error message and update your post.

Comment: And yes it is in the list, definitely the tester class that eclipse is trying to run. just failing to locate it for some reason. The message in bold is the exact error message. Nothing else

Comment: This is a case where a screen shot would probably help a lot. Package Explorer or Project Explorer, and the code of class in question.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of Eclipse you have a project view. Try right-clicking your Interface_Tester from there and in a dropdown choose run. May be you you are trying to run something else